# How to repeat video track using AVMutableComposition

Tags: iphone, video, avfoundation

I want to repeat 1s video to 10 seconds. I used AVMutableComposition and attached the code below.

When I try with a video recorded by apple default camera app, it works as well.

But I need to have specified video so that I made a customized camera. I made 1s video(frame rate : 5fps, H264 codec).

I am getting black frames with this video.

I am not sure whats the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself so I did not translate target view's coordinator when apply transform to video track so that it doesn't show up properly.